# How can I tunnel from one computer on a Wi-Fi connection to another specific machine on the LAN?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, bridging

I have 3 computers connected via Ethernet in 1 room

- 1 laptop with Windows 7 Ultimate.
- 1 laptop with Ubuntu 12.04.
- 1 PC with Windows 7 Ultimate.

Both laptops use their own independent Wi-Fi adapters for network connections, but the PC does not currently have an adapter. I built it strictly as a gaming rig and do not intend to use it for daily web surfing. I do not use the Ubuntu laptop for my Internet very much, so I want to use the Wi-Fi connection on that laptop and somehow pass it through my local network to the PC.

[image]

The Wi-Fi router is on another floor and the LAN is completely separate. Bridging the Wi-Fi and Ethernet adapters is out because it funkifies my network connections, and I am unable to access all the machines and synergy gets very confused.

What is the best way to go about forwarding the Internet connection from my Ubuntu laptop to the PC?

Answer (score 0):

Set up ip forwarding on your Ubuntu machine:

Edit /etc/sysctl.conf, find these lines and uncomment them like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then do

```
service network restart
```

Then set the ip address of the ubuntu machine as your default gateway on the windows machine.

Haven't tested this but I think it should work.